# Activate Steel Series Laptop Keyboard backlight on MSI GT72

Tags: 14.04, drivers, keyboard, laptop

After installing Linux 14.04 on my new MSI GT72 gaming laptop I can not seem to figure out how to get my back lite LEDs to work on my keyboard. The laptop has a steel series keyboard. I have searched for possible answers, but the closest I could find was some unable to find drivers for his external LED mouse. On Windows you would use the steel series engine to manage your LED keyboard. Is there a way to get them to work on Linux?

Thank you all for any help or advice!

Answer (score 3):

From my experience with Lenovo's Thinkpad keyboards I would at least try the following button combinations from the [MSI manual](http://us.msi.com/support/nb/GT72-Dominator-Pro-GTX-980M.html#down-manual):

[image]

Also check that you have installed the latest firmware, the following caught my attention:

> Support Fn/Win key swap function

If they can do that, then they should be able to implement at least basic backlight functionality like on other notebooks.

As always, make your voice heard, tell their support team nicely that you also want to use Ubuntu on the laptop and have the full experience.

Answer (score 0):

Having purchased the same laptop i can tell you that the backlight is initialised and controlled through the steel series utility bundled with your windows install. Notice how the LEDs don't come on until it initialises?

Unless an ubuntu steel series utility is released its not going to happen!

Answer (score 0):

On the new MSI Sword laptop, you hold down the FN Key located bottom right of keyboard and press the F8 key to turn on and repeatedly to dim the LED's or cycle through for on-dim-dimmer-dimmest then off. How did I find this to work? through hunt and peck..